# How can I pass a hidden value from my Thymeleaf template to a controller(Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm running a Spring Boot project and I'm trying to pass an id or the object using a post method but I keep returning null for the user. I would like to make the user available so that when the summary page is created(post method is hit for a separate form) the user I get from this can be added to the summary object.

I also believe there might be a way to pass the id with the anchor link?

This is my html:

```
        <div >
        <span th:text="${user.firstName}"></span> Summary Page
            <span th:text="${user.emailAddress}"></span>
            <form id="add" th:action="@{/addSummary}" method="post">
                <input id="userId" name="${user.userId}" type="hidden" value="${userId}"/>
          <!-- <input id="userId" name="${user}" type="hidden" value="${user}"/> -->
                <button type="submit" value="save">Add Summary</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<!-- another way to pass id? -->
<!--<a href="createSummary.html?user.id">AddSummary</a>-->
```

The controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/addSummary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addSummary(User user) {

    try{
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("views/createSummary");
        System.out.println("======POST Summary Method hit=====");
    //    model.addObject("summary", new Summary());
        User nUser = userService.findById(user.getUserId());
        model.addObject("user", nUser);
        System.out.println("user: " + nUser.getUserId());
        return model;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
- Thanks

Comment: An anchor will result in an HTTP Get request and the corresponding Controller method would need to use the @RequestParam to specify the user id.  If this is what you are asking?

Comment: ...and shouldn't your `value="${userId}"` be `value="${user.userId}"` -_not great with thymeleaf_ in which case its an id that is being passed to the controller not a User.

Comment: @TonyKennah thanks, I tried that as well but I'm not getting anything back. For passing the id in the link I was wondering if I could do something like pass the id that comes from the object already on the page (User) and send it to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the core problem with your code is that you try to use Thymeleaf expressions in non-Thymeleaf attributes, it will not work as expected. Thymeleaf will only look at attributes starting with `th:` (or `data-th-` if using HTML5 syntax).

For your case I would use `th:object` and `th:field`:

```xml
<form id="add" th:action="@{/addSummary}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
  <input id="userId" th:field="*{userId}" type="hidden"/>
  <button type="submit" value="save">Add Summary</button>
</form>
```

Reference: [Creating a Form in the Thymeleaf + Spring tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form).